# Swiftで独自クラスを保存する際にシリアライズ/デシリアライズでデータを保存/復元したいのですが、うまくいかない

Tags: swift

`TextField`に入力した文字を`シリアライズ`して`UserDefaults`で文字を保存して、`viewDidload`でアプリ起動時に、保存した文字を`デシリアライズ`して文字を復元して表示させたいのですが、表示されません。

どうすればよいでしょうか？ビルド自体はうまくいきます。

ちなみに`NSCoding`ではなく`NSSecureCoding`を使えばほぼ同じコードでうまくいきます。

```swift
// ViewController.swift
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var textField: UITextField!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let data = loadData()
        self.textField.text = data?.valueString
    }
    
    @IBAction func tapButton() {
        let data = MyClass()
        data.valueString = self.textField.text
        self.saveData(data)
    }
    
    
    func saveData(_ data: MyClass) {
        let userDefaults = UserDefaults.standard
        //シリアライズ(オブジェクトの内容をバイナリに変換)
        //カスタムクラス(MyClass)はそのままUserDefaultsで保存できないためシリアライズしてData型に変換する
        if let archiveData = try? NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: data, requiringSecureCoding: false) {
            userDefaults.setValue(archiveData, forKey: "valueSS")
            userDefaults.synchronize()
            print("シリアライズ成功")
        } else {
            print("シリアライズ失敗")
        }
    }
    
    func loadData() -> MyClass! {
        let userDefaults = UserDefaults.standard
        if let storedData: Data = userDefaults.object(forKey: "valueSS") as? Data {
            do {
                //デシリアライズ(バイナリをオブジェクトに変換)
                return try NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchivedObject(ofClass: MyClass.self, from: storedData)
                
            } catch {
                print("デシリアライズ失敗")
            }
        }
        return nil
    }
}
```

```swift
// MyClass.swift

import Foundation

class MyClass: NSObject, NSCoding {

    var valueString: String?

    override init() {
    }

    // load
    required init?(coder decoder: NSCoder) {
        if let valueString = decoder.decodeObject(forKey: "valueSS") as? String {
            self.valueString = valueString
        }
    }

    // save
    func encode(with coder: NSCoder) {
        coder.encode(self.valueString, forKey: "valueSS")
    }
}
```

Comment: 「ちなみに`NSCoding`ではなく`NSSecureCoding`を使えばほぼ同じコードでうまくいきます。」＞secureでない`NSCoding`は現在非推奨とされ、動かないようになっています。`NSSecureCoding`を使って動くコードがあるなら、そちらを使って下さい。なお、`UITextField`の内容を保存するといった用途なら、State Restorationの使用を検討してみて下さい。

Comment: 名前的にもSecureCodingの方を使った方がいいとは思ったのですが、実装できないのはおかしいと思い、質問させていただきました。

State Restorationを知らなかったのですが、State Restorationは画面に表示されるようなものに使えばいいということですかね？

Comment: 「画面に表示されるようなものに使えばいいということですかね？」＞そうです。ユーザの目に見える画面の状態を保存することを想定した機能です。

Comment: ありがとうございます。
さらに質問なのですが、カスラムクラスの配列を保存したい場合の方法がわからないのですが、どうしたらいいかわかりますでしょうか？

Comment: https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/74763/%e3%82%ab%e3%82%b9%e3%82%bf%e3%83%a0%e3%82%af%e3%83%a9%e3%82%b9%e3%81%ae%e9%85%8d%e5%88%97%e3%82%92userdafaults%e3%81%a8%e3%82%b7%e3%83%aa%e3%82%a2%e3%83%a9%e3%82%a4%e3%82%ba-%e3%81%a7%e3%82%b7%e3%83%aa%e3%82%a2%e3%83%a9%e3%82%a4%e3%82%ba%e3%81%a7%e4%bf%9d%e5%ad%98%e3%81%97%e3%81%9f%e3%81%84%e5%a0%b4%e5%90%88%e3%81%ae%e6%96%b9%e6%b3%95%e3%81%8c%e3%82%8f%e3%81%8b%e3%82%8a%e3%81%be%e3%81%9b%e3%82%93